# How do I maintain a session using Spring's WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, session

I am using Java and Spring in my application. I am trying to connect to an external SOAP webservices. The documentation suggests to maintain a session after the login call.

The code snippet provided by them is shown below:

```
AdminService_ServiceLocator locator = new AdminService_ServiceLocator();
adminBinding = (AdminServiceBindingStub) locator.getAdminService(adminServiceUrl);
adminBinding.setMaintainSession(true);
```

I am trying to do the same thing using WebServiceTemplate, but subsequent calls tell me that a session is needed by the endpoint. Below is the code I am using:

```
@Bean(name = "webServiceTemplate")
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
    final WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate(messageFactory());
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = marshaller();
    template.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    template.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    template.setDefaultUri(serverUrl);
```

Any suggestions on how I can maintain the session between the calls?

I know ideally this should be stateless, but this is necessary for a feature I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong Thanks, I've edited the post.